# How do i add an action to a JFrame JButton?

Tags: java, swing, button, jframe

I have a JFrame gui im making and I need help.
Im trying to find out how to add a action to my button.
as in using it in a "if" statement or make i print something out when you push it.

thanks!

code:

```
package agui;



import javax.swing.*;


public class Agui extends JFrame {
public Agui() {
    setTitle("My Gui");
    setSize(400, 400);


    JButton button = new JButton("click me");
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    panel.add(button);

    this.getContentPane().add(panel);

    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Agui a = new Agui();
}



}
```

Comment: Read up on Listeners

Answer (score 3):

You want the "addActionListener" method, something like:

```
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("You clicked the button");
          }
        });
```